# Error messages eaten somewhere along exec-maven-plugin > Node.js > r.js

Tags: node.js, maven, requirejs, stderr

We're using [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to run RequireJS's optimizer (r.js) under Node.js (because it's a lot faster than Rhino):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compile-js</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>${node.executable}</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>${project.build.directory}/dependency/requirejs/r.js</argument>
                    <argument>-o</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The issue is, whenever there's any issue during compilation, the error messages that r.js is supposed to blurt out are not shown in Maven's console output. What I do to troubleshoot is, I rerun the Maven command with the -X flag to get debug output so that exec-maven-plugin outputs the actual command being executed. It's something like:

```
project-root/target/dependency/node/node \
    project-root/target/dependency/requirejs/r.js \
    -o src/main/webapp/app.build.json
```

When I run the command manually from the command line, I then get the actual compilation errors in the console and then proceed to fixing them.

I've experimented with redirecting stderr to stdout with `2>&1` to no avail (on Windows) because I couldn't immediately find a way to make exec-maven-plugin like the redirection bit as an argument. I didn't pursue that route too far because it's just a wild guess that this is a stderr/stdout issue -- it could be, but I'm merely speculating.

Any pointers to as to what may be happening, or any suggestions for further diagnostic steps that I can take? Please remember there are multiple moving parts in this problem: Maven, exec-maven-plugin, Node.js, r.js, and one tired head.

P.S. I'm considering giving [requirejs-maven-plugin](https://github.com/mcheely/requirejs-maven-plugin) a shot as a last resort because the project timeline doesn't allow me to do a complete overhaul of the POM right now. I'm trying to see if there's anything I can do with the current setup.

Comment: Did you try using the `outputFile` parameter?

Comment: @aib Yes. Unfortunately it doesn't do anything due to a known bug with exec-maven-plugin: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MEXEC-86

Comment: In your last resort bag, please consider [jszip maven plugin](http://jszip.org) it is another Rhino based one though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about wrapping the call to `node.js` and `r.js` in a script, that you then call from the `maven-exec` plugin?

From a look at `r.js`, it seems to use `console.log` for it's output. Maybe running it from a shell script will allow you to catch the output, pipe it into a file, regex for an errors, etc.

Depending on the OS, this might be easy to do.

Comment: Yes, this could potentially work. Though, due to how our build environment works inside temporary mapped drives, it's hard for me to get a hold of the resultant file unless. I'd rather find a way to get the errors appear in the console. Perhaps, your suggestion + a 2>&1 to remap stderr to stdout.

Comment: I meant that you should pipe the output into a file inside the script (using 2>&1), then you could do a `cat file` from inside the script, or use something like `grep` to look for errors. You shouldn't have to physically access the files, I agree.